# how to cache other methods from the same class?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, jcache

I'm using Ehcache implementation of JCache.

Lets say, I've class `Test`. In this class I've two methods: `methodA` and `methodB`. `methodB` has annotation `@CacheResult(cacheName = "methodB")`.

From this informations you would guess that I'd like to have cached method `methodB` and `methodA` should use this cache.

But... It does not work. When I'm using methods from the same class, it seems like this annotation is not firing its interceptor. It works though if I create class `Test2` and move method `methodB` to this class - then, as expected, the result of this method is cached.

How can I enable caching methods from the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, it seems impossible - if we stick to `CacheResult` annotations.

This is because interceptors are not fired correctly when class is using its methods by `this` reference - and not by CDI. If we want to cache them, we need to use another way or just call some static method, lets say `cacheMe`, inside every `private` method.